# Can I show the disk space requirement for a component that's not being installed in the [Files] section in Inno Setup?

Tags: components, inno-setup, diskspace

Is it possible to show the disk space requirement for a component that's not being installed in the `[Files]` section?
In my case this component is the SQL installer executable file.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[Setup]` section has an `ExtraDiskSpaceRequired` parameter, also the `[Components]` section.